# VC++ programs build in Windows 7 don't run on Windows Xp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp

I have created a small `WIN32 Console Application` in Visual C++ in Windows 7.

When I try to run this application on Windows Xp it gives me an error saying

> This application has failed to start
>   because MSVCR100D.dll was not found. 
>   Re-installing the application may fix
>   this problem.

So how do I statically build this application so that it contains `MSVCR100D.dll` ? or

do I have to copy `MSVCR100D.dll` form Windows 7 and paste it some where in Windows Xp ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSVCR100D.dll isn't a Win7 DLL, it's an MSVC2010 DLL. You can use static linking by changing RuntimeLibrary from MD(d) to MT(d) in the project properties (under C/C++ -> Code Generation).

Comment: Do you know what to change in Code Generation? Is it Runtime Library?

Comment: Alternatively you could install the VC++ 2010 run-time libraries (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displaylang=en) on the WinXP machine, but this would only help if you built your app for a Retail configuration (the 'D' in MSVCR100D.dll indicates you're building for Debug). You're not allowed to distribute the Microsoft debug DLLs to other machines.

Comment: @PhilMY Thanks for your valuable advice. : )